# Highmap Geojson of China cities

Tags: highcharts, geojson

I am working on Highcharts Maps of china, but can not find the city level Geojson to implement.
https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/
I can find the only Province Geojson

Answer (score 0):

All available maps you can find in the `Highmaps map collection`. If the map which you are looking for doesn't exist there that means that you will need to create it by yourself. How to do it you can find here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps

You can also report the idea about creating those maps here: https://github.com/highcharts/map-collection-dist/issues